# Not able to link GLEW to a project using CMake

Tags: cmake, static-linking, dynamic-linking, glew

May someone recommend me, how could I link my project to the GLEW via cmake.

For instance, I did well for the GLFW, according to its documentation:

```
...
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/application/dependencies/GLFW)
...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_MAIN})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw)
```

I haven't found the good documentation by GLEW. I also would note I've installed [this](https://github.com/Perlmint/glew-cmake) version of the GLEW, where CMakeLists.txt located in the root directory. I've tried different options, however the project not capable to find the glwe lib.

My best attempt looks like:

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/application/dependencies/GLEW)
...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_MAIN})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/application/dependencies/GLEW/include)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw GLEW)
```

But, it seems foolish. I mean if I properly comprehend, glew's CMake generates static/dynamic lib, and at the next step I link one to the project. However, it's still not able to detect glew lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no CMake target called `GLEW` in the linked project.  The library targets are called `libglew_static` and `libglew_shared`. You should be using the library targets as defined in the glew project `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Thank you a lot!